# What's the difference between IISAdministration and WebAdministration

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-10, web-administration

Here's the docs for both modules:

- [`IISAdministration` Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
- [`WebAdministration` Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

And here's a couple articles detailing the release notes  of IISAdministration

- [Introducing IISAdministration in the PowerShell Gallery](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery)
- [IISAdministration PowerShell Cmdlets | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets)

It seems that `IISAdministration` is the newer utility as of **IIS 10.0**

**Questions**

1. Should `IISAdministration` be preferred over `WebAdministration` where possible?
2. What are the major differences between the two?

Comment: MS covers this in their What's New for IIS 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets . Basically, `IISAdministration` is newer and faster, with some other benefits.

Comment: If you hit any issue with WebAdministration (in fact a lot due to the original design), it is not likely to change any more. Use IISAdministration and that's the future. Note that IISAdministration has been back ported to IIS 8.x, so not exclusive to IIS 10.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this article can clarify your doubts: [IIS PowerShell modules and OS versions](https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell#iis-powershell-modules-and-os-versions)

> IISAdministration has one big advantage; the types returned by the
> commands are much more useful. While they are still XML wrappers, they
> are adorned with useful properties and methods that make the objects
> much more usable without relying on the commands:
>
> If you’re using the old WebAdministration, you pretty much have to do
> everything with the PowerShell CmdLets or by embracing the XML.
> There’s no way to navigate from a site returned by Get-Website to its
> applications, as one simple example. The new module also works much
> better with PowerShell pipelining.